# How Can I install ruby on Redhat? ruby package not found

Tags: ruby, rhel

I dont' know why I cannot install ruby through yum in my RHEL6.2
How can I fix it. I don't wanna install through source. Any idea?

```
[root@kithost ~]# yum install ruby
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package ruby available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

RVM is a solution but it is not that I want.

What I want to know is that once we can't find any package from yum, what kind of thing should we fix into order to let yum find it?

Comment: Perhaps rvm is the best choice to install ruby on any platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redhat does not have a free repo list unless you pay, or make subscription to them.

The reason for that I cannot install ruby is that there is no availalbe repo list

check

/etc/repo.list

you can copy the one from CentOS to Redhat.

Then your yum could search a available repo server and make your ruby downloadable.

Comment: Hey, where can I find a CentOS repo.list?

Comment: start up a centos VM, check inside the /etc/repo.list

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best way to install and manage Ruby is using [RVM](https://rvm.io/). Moreover, you can use more than one ruby versions using RVM. I can bet, it's really something you may love it. Yum is sometime a curse :-).

Follow their [installation guide](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) as there are different methods of (with pros and cons) installations and choose your preferred one. I'm pretty sure, you will love it too.

However, if you are still thinking to use it, you may follow [this Guide](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Getting_and_Installing_Ruby). Be aware, I don't not know whether it works or not as I did not try it. Why should I try something else, when I'm already using BEST one :)!

Comment: Do you know How can i locate the ruby package using yum ??

Comment: I think he's looking for a system version of Ruby, and not one just for a single user. Unless you can install RVM for global use.

Answer (score 0):

RVM is a good solution but I found that [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) was much better including when you have to use Ruby on a server.

You can find how to install rbenv in [the README](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#-2-installation).